# how have an optimize and good update statement in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a statement to update for example `is_new` to 0 with a condition like `mail.user_id=$user.id` etc.

```
update mails set `is_new=0` WHERE `mails.user_id=$user.id`
```

should i add another condition for prevent updating records that already have `is_new` equal to zero? like this

```
update mails set is_new=0 WHERE mails.user_id=$user.id and is_new!=0
```

which statment is the best? and do u think it's required to have second condition too?

Comment: yes ofcourse, your second condition will reduce execution time

Comment: You may want to update NULLs, too. Then: `and is_new <> 0 or is_new is null)`.

Comment: MySQL docs state this: `If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.`. So, you don't need second condition. Just keep things simple.

Comment: Can you share the link? Also, what if the condition would not be =, but something else? We need to think in ideas. Also, the documentation might be wrong as well. Benchmarking and testing is the keyword

Comment: @LajosArpad - [here it is](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html). Hit CTRL + F and look for the text I quoted.

Comment: Point taken, the documentation states this indeed. However, if it was my project and I would badly need to optimize, I would check the validity of the quote with experiments.

Comment: It is good style to only update what must be updated. The documentation says nothing about triggers being fired or not in the case the value already has the desired value. (BTW: In my comment above I forgot the opening parenthesis after `and`.)

Answer (score 1):

As a very general principle, I structure my UPDATE queries to only "touch" the records that actually need touching. In my mind this is less for performance reasons and more for readability reasons: the latter form of the query more precisely states what you're trying to do -- namely, you want to set `is_new=0` for only those records where `is_new` is not already 0. So for that reason alone, I'd say the extra condition should be present.

On a more general note, there's a famous computer science quote that "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". When working with MySQL queries I don't always agree with this quote, but it makes an important point: **If you're getting hung up about whether to optimize something, and you haven't actually tried out the two formats and/or taken measurements to determine how much difference the optimization makes, you're wasting your time.** If you're optimizing without knowing what difference it will make, **the only outcome you know for certain is that you're making your job more complicated.**

So don't optimize for performance reasons until you **know** (or have strong reasons to believe) that the optimization will make a difference. But *always* optimize for readability and standardization reasons, since you *do* know that people will have to read your code in the future. At least that's my rule.

Comment: Adding the condition has no chance of improving performance. Even if the column is indexed. Adding the condition to check that `is_new != 0` actually improves chances of the query being slower.

Comment: Depends on the actual speed a write is issued, the actual speed a condition is checked, the number of elements to be updated and the subset where is_new is not already 0. Instead of chances and opinions, benchmarking will have the final say

Comment: Thanks for the extra info guys. I guess my point above is that it's not worth optimizing for speed until you have good reason to think speed will be a problem; but it *is* worth structuring your query in the way that makes it as clear as possible what it's doing, even if that means adding an extra WHERE condition (unless this causes some horrific performance problems, in which case see above).

Comment: @LajosArpad - not really. The thing that kills performance is the condition itself - it's a boolean field. No indexing can help to reduce data set MySQL has to inspect. You get the scenario where MySQL finds records using `user_id`. Then it needs to re-check that data-set for `is_new != 0` and possibly reduce it further. Then it needs to write to what it found. While writing, it *still* checks whether the data should be updated. The step with `is_new !=0` is completely redundant. It just hurts everything, it won't help MySQL do less work.

Comment: @N.B., I cannot agree, nor disagree, since I do not have the source-code of MySQL in front of me. I believe you do not have its source-code either in front of you. As a result, we can only guesstimate. This means that we do not know what the truth really is, we can only argue based on our opinions, observations and documentation quotes. The real thing is benchmarking. If MySQL does not execute the update, as you have quoted, then you are probably right. If not, then you might be wrong. Experiments are needed in these kinds of optimizations. Not to mention that if the operator was <

Comment: @N.B. I agree, but would an index `(user_id, is_new)`, while almost certainly overkill, allow the check to hit the index?

Comment: which is the smaller operator, then it would optimize. I am not sure how the filtering is executed and I believe both of us can state our opinions, which are little more than blind guesses. The condition is redundant IF we can rely this statement on benchmark results.

Comment: @Arth - it's irrelevant if it would be checked or not, it produces the same work load as scanning the table. You can force the index, it still reduces the data set using `user_id` first. Since the `is_new` has 2 possible values, it's totally useless since MySQL has to go through the entire list again anyway. If I'm not mistaken, index selectivity must be 17.5% or something like that for MySQL to determine it's quicker to use index than table scan (not sure on that number though).

Comment: @N.B., your point if perfectly valid if we assume that the statement in the documentation is true. However, we still need guarantee and if there was another operator, then this knowledge would not be applicable. Also, you cannot know that is_new can have two values. It is an educated guess indeed, but we do not really know that as a fact.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I usually believe what docs say. However, [here's the source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_update.cc).  Skim through comments, but I think even C++ code is readable enough so we can safely determine that MySQL indeed checks the current row value with new row value. The check is *much* cheaper than write operation so it also makes sense.  Anyway, I'm not coming from an opinion here, I dealt with performance penalties due to similar optimization attempts.

Comment: Omg you guys! I believe everything you're saying but I really don't think it's in the realm of relevant to what the OP was asking. Reread the question, the author clearly isn't in a space to be worrying about nitpicks like this. ;-)

Comment: @TopherHunt - I don't think this particular case is a nitpick. It might look like that, but for example - the condition makes no sense, doesn't make things readable and it has potential to kill the performance. We went into "nitpicking" about performance. The question is about whether it makes sense to add the `is_new != 0`. It doesn't, since it bears 0 benefits and has the *potential* to screw things up. It's one of those things that can kill performance to the point you have no idea where to look for the culprit.

Comment: @NB See my answer above, I think it's debatable that it has 0 benefits. At least in my case. As for the performance risks, I'll defer to you but none of my apps have blown up yet after using tricks like this for a few years.

Comment: @TopherHunt - point taken, but how many MySQL databases you have that go well beyond terabyte mark? I believe that avoiding setting bombs simply keeps you healthy developer. This, even though it looks funny and giggly and irrelevant has great potential to be one of those things that just kicks you in the ass when you don't need it. Anyway, to each his own. I tried to highlight the opposite site where things don't work as you expect them to. This is one of those.

Comment: @N.B., point taken again. This is done, at least for version 5.7. This means that in this particular case, at least for version 5.7 your opinion is valid. Which naturally leads us to the assumption that probably many versions comply to the criteria. However, I believe that my answer still shows a philosophical point, from which, this particular case is an exception, as you have rightly pointed out.

Comment: @LajosArpad - we've taken this too far IMO, but still - here are [some docs about MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/update.html) so the "at least" goes back to 4.1 although I'm sure 3.23 implements the same behaviour since it's a huge optimization :)

Comment: It is never too far, it is good to have the docs in one place :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when you set the value in your update, it is effectively overwriting the old value, which takes longer than checking whether the value should be overriden. So, you have the following cases:

Case1: You `update` every `is_new` to `0`

- if `user_id` matches and `is_new` is not `0`, then it will correctly be updated to `0`
- if `user_id` matches and `is_new` is already `0`, then it will `update` it to `0`, but it will take a longer time, since it is a write operation

Case2: You `set` `is_new` to `0` if it is not already `0`

- if `user_id` matches and `is_new` is not `0`, then it will check whether it is `0` and consequently and correctly update it to `0`
- if `user_id` matches and `is_new` is already `0`, then it will check whether it is `0` and will leave the record as it is

Let's suppose you have to `update` `x` records , however, from the `x` records, only `y` have a not `0` is_new. Checking whether `is_new` is `0` takes `a` time and updating `is_new` to `0` takes `b` time for a record on average. In this case:

If you do not filter out the records where `is_new` is already `0`, then:
you will `update` all the records, which takes `x * b` time.

If you filter out the records where `is_new` is already `0`, then:
you will check `is_new` for the records, which takes `x * a` and then you will update `y` records, which takes `y * b`.

Intuitively, I believe that writing takes so much time, that:

```
x * a + y * b < x * b
```

However, the sure thing would be to benchmark it and see some measurements, because no one on earth will tell you how your mysql executes your query under the hood.

EDIT:

Based on comments, apparently, the documentation states that if a field is updated to its current value, then MySQL will notice the issue and will not execute the update.

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

This does not change the fact that in case an optimization is needed, experiments should be done, since, if the quote is proven wrong, it would not be the first time a documentation is flawed. Also, the ideas should be useful for other cases as well, since the quote only touches conditions with the = operator and in case other conditions should be checked, the quoted MySQL feature would be inapplicable.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience and from my opinion, the answer is clear here - do not add `is_new != 0`. There are several reasons and I'll try to list them:

- SQL is about explaining *what* you want to do. Adding the condition would be also *telling how* to do it. MySQL is optimized enough to avoid working more than it should.
- Adding the condition doesn't make your query more readable. Removing it does. It clearly states you want to update `is_new` to a value based on `user_id`
- Adding the condition has the *potential* to hurt performance. Note the word *potential* - I'm not saying it will, but it might. If you can't optimize how something works, why would you potentially make it slower? Just don't. In your case, we're probably talking about abysmal performance values, but still.
- Adding the condition will make MySQL do more work. Not much, but still - it will just do more. You don't really need it.
- MySQL performs a check whether the row has indeed changed before writing anything new to it. If the `is_new` was `0` and you want to set it to `0` again - MySQL will notice that and it will skip updating that row (write operation is much more costly than a check operation, so MySQL will perform that check).

Quote from manual:

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

Relevant source code, if needed: [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/sql/sql_update.cc)